# How to re-create a vertical Card Slider, similar to Refokus

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to recreate the vertical Card Slider that slides images into the screen as user scrolls. How can I re-create this? It looks like it uses very basic HTML, Css perspective-3d, and js. But I can't recreate it. Can you please help me out here? I am trying to understand how the slider is working and replicate the slider 1:1 : https://2022.refokus.com

[Here's an example of the slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6T6kH.png)

Comment: Just try an attempt. If you fail to achieve your prefer output, then add an *Minimal, Reproducible Example* so we can try to check and point it out the correction(s).

Comment: I would try to do it with three.js - [link](https://threejs.org/)

Comment: Yep so they also using three.js on their page

Comment: I'm complete noob with Js I tried to look into the javascript but couldn't figure it out

Comment: three.js has great documentations and a lot of examples. But you also can use youtube and search for "three.js website" for step-by-step tutorials.